# how to access object data within object

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
const paymentIntents = await stripe.paymentIntents.list({
    stripeAccount: stripe_account
});
```

and it returns:

```
object: 'list',
  data: [
    {
      id: 'pi_...',
      object: 'payment_intent',
      amount: 2500,
```

now I have two problems. 1. I need to access `amount`. and 2. there is going to be dozens of records being returned, so I need to loop through all the results and actually add up the `amounts`. here's what I've tried so far:

```
console.log(paymentIntents.amount)
console.log(paymentIntents.data.amount)
```

neither of those worked. and i wouldn't even know how to loop thorugh all those results. How can i do this?

Comment: `paymentIntents.data` is an array so you should index it before access the amount property. `paymentIntents.data[0].amount` will return `2500`.

Comment: @AlexSp3 ohh i see that makes sense okay. So to loop through the array then, would i do something like `for (var i = 0; i < paymentIntents.length; i++{` and theoretically I should be able to access all the records, and get all values for `paymentIntents.data[0].amount` by doing `paymentIntents.data[i].amount`?

Comment: Correct, only that you should iterate for `i < paymentIntents.data.length`

Comment: @AlexSp3 aweosme thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce like this:

```
const paymentIntents = {object: 'list', data: [{
      id: 'pi_...',
      object: 'payment_intent',
      amount: 2500}, {
      id: 'pi_...',
      object: 'payment_intent_2',
      amount: 3500,
}]}
const amount = paymentIntents.data.reduce((previous, current, index, array) => {  
 const sum = current.amount + previous.amount; 
 return sum; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that if you expect to come close to the limit of 100 results for a list request, you should make sure to handle [pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination), for example using the [autopagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=node) supported by `stripe-node`:

```
let total = 0
stripe.paymentIntents.list({limit: 5})
  .autoPagingEach(function(pi) {
    total += pi.amount
  });
```

Note that this structure requires iteration, and precludes the use of `reduce`-type solutions in the other answers. If your expected result set won't come close to the 100 item limit, then set your limit appropriately and don't worry about this.

Comment: okay good to know, thank you. I see on your profile you seem to answer a lot of stripe questions. I am running into a weird problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761436/use-payment-method-for-stripe-paymentintent . i woudl appreiacte the help

Answer (score 0):

```html
const paymentIntents = await stripe.paymentIntents.list({
    stripeAccount: stripe_account
});

const total = paymentIntents.data.reduce(
  (listTotal, line) => listTotal + line.amount,
  0
);
```